# Setting up an online server database and code my android native app to interact with it

Tags: php, android, sql, html, web

Im developing a very simple native Android App containing a simple Main Menu with the Today, Yesterday, This Week, This Month and Search by Date options.

[image]

(I bought the lynda course: "Building Android and iOS Apps with Dreamweaver" with HTML5 and with the design and functionality of the app im not having too much trouble.)

What i entend with this app is this: i will write famous people profiles every day (between 1 and 5). So when people click (for example) in the Today option they will access to the profiles list that i have created for today (Yesterday and others is a check on the past written profiles from database).

So imagine that some android user clicked on today and will be presented with 3 profiles options ("Brad Pitt", "Shakira" and "Cristiano Ronaldo"), that i need the app to access my server database to update it (the "Today" profiles).

[image]

and finally...

[image]

Before the questions i want to say that i have searched on stackoverflow and found very similar answers, but im a novice on programming and when i'm reading the answers they can differ so much that i got confused going link on link documentation.

The Questions:

1. I want to create somekind of method that i could have a template with different profiles (Singer, Politician, Soccer Player) and click on somekind of button to start a new profile/article with Born Date, Occupation, Nationality, Biography and etc. Its this possible? How can i do it and in wich programming language?
2. What kind of server and what kind of database do i have to create and how to configure it to send the info to my app?
3. There is any server specifications that i must have for this to work the smoother and easiest possible? For this issue price is not a problem.
4. What kind of code should i write on my app so that it could get the "3 profiles update for today" from my website?
5. Its possible to show me some code example that would work with this simple step in my app of selectiong "Today" button on main menu and the app check for new profiles for today and present the user as an option? Because if i had this bit of code i could understand better how to do the rest with the profile details on the "Brad Pitt" option for example.

Hope you understood my questions. Thanks in advance. Have a nice day

Comment: youir "(C) 2012" makes no sense. It should be rather (C) <who> 2012, unless I missed the point of year holding copyrights :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the `Phonegap` Framework to develop your application, I would do it like so:
First of all get a Server/Webspace capable of running `PHP` Scripts and a `MySQL Database`.
 
You also have to rethink the way these applications work, for example you can't

> configure it to send the info to my app

You need a Server Side Script (i would choose `PHP` for this, it's easy to learn and available on almost every Server). This PHP Script then queries your `MySQL Database` where all the information about the people is stored. On thing to remember is that your Clients will poll the server and request the content, you're not actively sending anything to Clients unless requested, that's just the way how `HTTP` works. The interface your Script is providing there is called a [REST](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/) Interface.
Have a look at the link, it explains everything pretty good. Your output format should be `JSON` this makes it really nice to work with in the Client App later on. To do things like "what was posted today?" Have a look at how SQL Queries work and implement it in your Script. 
Now for the client you can access this data by using `JavaScript`, most likely `jQuery` to simplify everything a bit. Use the jQuery [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function to access the data provided by your `REST Interface`. Now you can use basic jQuery to wrap this data up with `HTML` to present it to the user. I know that this is not "example code" or anything you requested, but it should point you into the right direction on how to achieve something like you want to do. Just do a google search for all the keywords listed above and keep reading about it, then you should be able to build a app like that.

Comment: Thank god! Your answer helped me more than days of research by myself because it really looks like a guide i would even pay for. Honestly i wasnt expecting such a precise answer. I will get to work and if you dont mind i'll be posting my doubts in the process. Once again thank you.